# QGIS 2 web openlayers - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to draw features in the OpenLayers map geerated by QGIS2web plugin. Since eveything seems to be alright and all the features come out now, [unlike the recent situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69181018/qgis2web-openlayers-drawing-features-cant-draw-rectangle).

My full code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/go39r4j7/

but I am not convinced enough about the situation, as I keep getting the error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')**

[image]

which points out the following piece of code:

```
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") 
   == undefined)) {
        var doPopup = false;
        for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                doPopup = true;
              }
          }
```

Theoretically, I know, that I can't access the object, which is null:

https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-null

but any options I tried (removing this piece of code, removing the `layer.get` property, changing the `layer.get("interactive")` to my own id (`"draw"`)) weren't successful.

Moroever this piece of code appears to be standard for similar situations like this:

https://gist.github.com/riccardoklinger/e3e2c512a366c8a6a296c10eef9c4162

How can I fix this issue? The tool works, although I am concerned about future modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel

> Feature callback. The callback will be called with two arguments. The first
> argument is one feature or render feature at the pixel, the second is
> the layer of the feature and will be null for unmanaged layers.

If you have an unmanaged layer (e.g. the overlay layer used by a Draw interaction) you will need to ensure you have a layer before using `.get` on it:

```
if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && layer && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
```

Comment: Yes, I have it, as I've mentioned in my code earlier. I am wondering how to fix the error in the console.

Comment: Insert `layer &&`  in the `if` statement before attempting to call `.get`

Comment: Like this? 
if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer && layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
the error is still the same

Comment: OK this one:
 if (feature instanceof ol.Feature && layer && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
            if (layer) { 
                var doPopup = false;
                for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
                    if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                        doPopup = true;
                    }
                }
```